# ElasticSearch 6.2.3 integrating with Spring Data/Spring Batch for indexing

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-batch

I have installed ElasticSearch 6.2.3 version in my local machine. I have a requirement to index the data which I am getting it from webservices. I have to use some spring framework for this indexing activity. Is that advisable to use Spring Batch / Spring Data along with Spring Boot.

I am trying ElasticSearch 6.2.3 integrating with Spring Data, but later some time I came to know that Spring Data doesn't have support for ElasticSearch 6.2.3 version.

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: spring-data-elasticsearch 3.1.0 should work with elasticsearch 6.2.3, do you need to index ws responses for logging and monitoring only?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that advisable to use Spring Batch / Spring Data along with Spring Boot.

Yes, a Spring Batch job is a good candidate for this kind of uses cases.

You can find an extension for Spring Batch to index documents in ElasticSearch here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-elasticsearch

Hope this helps.